# Adding a template to a specific page

Tags: theming

I want to have a template for a specific page, as I want to add multiple Javascript pulled games to it.

The nid is 34, so to create this page, I would have to create `page--node--34.tpl.php`, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.

Once you've added the file, clear the caches and the new template will take effect.

Comment: Do I need to declare this new template file anywhere else?

Comment: No, as you've overriding an existing template (page.tpl.php) you don't need to declare it anywhere. Just put the file somewhere in your theme folder (under /templates by convention) and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify the version of Drupal you're using, but if it's 7 the correct naming structure is: `node--34.tpl.php`. Ensure you clear the cache after adding it to your theme or theme/template folder.

Comment: To override a _page_ template it's `page--node--34.tpl.php`. For a _single node_ template, it's `node--34.tpl.php`. OP is asking about the former, not the latter

Comment: As a page can be a node in this case you can use either.

Comment: No you can't - a node and a page are completely different things, not interchangeable in any way. page.tpl.php is auto-wrapped with html.tpl.php, node.tpl.php is used in a variety of different contexts. A page can _contain_ a node in the content area, it can even be the full-page representation _of_ a node - but it's never a node, it's a page. What you're suggesting can't work, just try it

Comment: I actually have it functioning on a few Drupal7 sites as we speak. Created a basic page node (nid of 345), then created a template: node--345.tpl.php, cleared cache, and voila. When you create a "basic page" (straight out of drupal core) it is assigned a nid (node id), so yes, when you create a new basic page within Drupal it is a node. Creating any content from the "node/add" is creating a new node.

Comment: We're talking about 2 different things - the OP wants to override page.tpl.php for a specific node, _not_ node.tpl.php for a specific node. They're completely different files, with different content. page.tpl.php contains the theme regions, one of those being main_content, where node.tpl.php will eventually be rendered. You can't alter theme regions/page structure in node.tpl.php, because it isn't the page template, and doesn't contain them. The core `theme_hook_suggestions` for a page template let you use `page--foo--bar.tpl.php` for a path like "foo/bar", that's what we're talking about here